# Left Aligning Caption of One Table But Not The Others

Tags: tables, captions, align

I need to format a document with all the caption of all tables at the start of the page aligned to the left margin, and the caption of all tables in the body of the page centered. I have seen similar questions online about aligning the caption of a table using the caption package. However, this changes the alignment of all of the caption in the document. Is there a way to change the alignment of the caption of a single table?

Comment: Is it known at the time of writing whether or not a given `table` environment is placed at the top of a page?

Comment: No, I am not sure how to identify the tables position on the page. I can view the tables once the document has been complied, however I do not know how to adjust the caption position of only those tables. Furthermore, all the tables have the ```[!htb]``` command, however I do not know how to ask LaTeX which location it choose to position the table at before the document has been compiled.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Is there a way to change the alignment of the caption of a single table?

There sure is, and it makes use of the machinery of the `caption` package as well.

[image]

You mention in a follow-up comment that you will know only *after* the document is compiled whether or not a given `table` will be placed at the top of a page. I guess you will then have edit your file to insert suitable `\captionsetup` directives and recompile the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%% Set the default caption justification method: raggedright, aka left-aligned
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!] 
\caption{Default caption justification style: \texttt{raggedright}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!] 
%% override the default:
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Alternative caption justification style: \texttt{centering}} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!] 
\caption{Back to default, i.e., raggedright, caption  justification style} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```